# Javascript - Approximate Number

Tags: javascript, integer, rounding

I was wondering if it is possible to get the approximate number in Javascript? Like if I had a large number for example

```
var number = 537989;
```

A bit like the Math.round() , just so it rounds up to 538000. Is there a way to do so? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try dividing by `10,000`, then applying `round()`?

Comment: @frederichamidi why did you delete the answer?

Comment: The answer was deleted by its owner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write it yourself. Something like

```
function myround(number, precision = 1000) {
    var result = Math.round(number / precision) *  precision;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Precision should be an argument ;)

Comment: Sure :) I'll rephrase: The function would be more useful if precision was an argument. Not _necessary_ in this case of course.

Comment: Addition of an optional argument is trivial: `precision = Math.pow(10,(precision || 0));`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a JS library, [approximate-number](https://www.npmjs.com/package/approximate-number), that does this and a bit more. For example, `537989` would get approximated to `"537k"` by default or `"538k"` if you set `round: true`.